# English translation of Borel-Serre, Le théorème de Riemann-Roch?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, translation, coherent-cohomology

Would be happy to receive a translation in English of Borel and Serre's *Le théorème de Riemann-Roch*, Bulletin de la Société Mathématique de France, Tome 86 (1958) pp. 97-136, doi:[10.24033/bsmf.1500](https://doi.org/10.24033/bsmf.1500), [EuDML](https://eudml.org/doc/86949).

Comment: an English translation does not seem to exist; for a Russian translation, see http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=mat&paperid=193&option_lang=eng

Answer (score 21):

I have just finished this translation! Here is the TeX source, and here is a (live) PDF. Hopefully there shouldn't be too many mistakes :-)

Edit: due to moving links, it's probably best if I just leave the following, where all my translations can be found: [thosgood.com/translations](https://thosgood.com/translations).

Comment: Fantastic! And thanks for the dictionary for translating math terms at https://thosgood.com/maths-dictionary/